# Media Player is null when back to Screen

Tags: javascript, java, android-mediaplayer

so I have this code on my settings Activity and it works very good. but if I start the music, and than I am going to the main activity and back to the Settings, if I am trying to stop the music it is not working. when I back to the settings activity suddenly the background music is null(while the music is playing), so the music is not stopping when i push the button to stop(it is not entering the if).

```
private void stopSounds() {
    if (backGroundMusic!=null) {
        if(backGroundMusic.isPlaying()) {
            backGroundMusic.stop();
            backGroundMusic.reset();
            backGroundMusic.release();
          //  backGroundMusic = null;
        }
    }
}
private void playSounds() {
   // stopSounds();
    backGroundMusic = new MediaPlayer();
    backGroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background);
    backGroundMusic.start();
}
```

}

Comment: You're setting backGroundMusic to null..

Comment: still the same problem without this line. you can see my edit